# Inline instanced class as parameter in an Enum

Tags: java, class, enums, instance, css

I'm new in java programming and trying to learn it.
I ran into a problem that cannot find a solution for it in the web:

I have an enum, that is a "list" of actions and each of them has a property 
of type Actions that conains a list of possible subactions. The subacions are constant string.

I'd like to instanziate a anonymus instance of Actions in the enum constructor so that 
in addition to the standart subactions, each enum could have its subactions

I tried to write an enum like the following

```
public enum Action {
    ACTION1("One", new Actions(){
        public static final String TEST = "test";
    }),
    ACTION2("TWO", null),
    ACTION3("THREE,null);

    private final String act;
    public final Actions actions;

    private Action(String act, Actions actions) {
        this.act = act;
        this.actions = actions;
    }
}
```

and this is Actions class

```
public class Actions {
    public static final String SUBACTION_TEST1 = "suoOne";
    public static final String SUBACTION_TEST2 = "subTwo";
}
```

than, this is how I use the Action enum:

```
String as = Action.ACTION1.params.SUBACTION_TEST1;
```

and up to here it wors but I'cannot write this:

```
String ast = Action.ACTION1.params.TEST;
```

I know that probably this approach is wrong but before the change the implementation
I'd like to know why doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean `actions` rather than `params`. `actions` has a type `Actions` which doesn't have a field TEST.  You could cast to the subclass of `Actions` if it had a name, but it doesn't

Comment: so my goal is hopeles using this code?

Comment: I think its worth reviewing what you want to do to see if it can be done another way.

Answer (score 3):

Your enum has no property named `params`, which is the immediate reason your code example does not work. One thing you could do to improve this design, is to have your `Actions` class return the list of sub-actions via a well defined method:

```
public class Actions {
    public static final String SUBACTION_TEST1 = "suoOne";
    public static final String SUBACTION_TEST2 = "subTwo";

    public List<String> getSubActions() {
        return Arrays.asList(SUBACTION_TEST1, SUBACTION_TEST2);
    }
}

public enum Action {
    ACTION1("One", new Actions(){
        public static final String TEST = "test";

        @Override
        public List<String> getSubActions() {
            return Arrays.asList(TEST);
        }
    }),

    private final String act;
    private final Actions actions;

    private Action(String act, Actions actions) {
        this.act = act;
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    public Actions getActions() {
        return actions;
    }
}
```

And to use this:

```
List<String> subActionList = Action.ACTION1.getSubActions();
```

Comment: Yea, You're right but param is residual of my original code I reduced for this post.
    String as = Action.ACTION1.actions.SUBACTION_TEST1;<<--- this is right

but I want to use this syntax to access to subparams:
    String as = Action.ACTION1.actions.TEST;

Comment: @EmergencyExit - That kind of dynamic property access is not supported in Java. `Action.ACTION1.actions` resolves to the `Actions` class, not to the inner class you defined in your enum.